# Conditionally command line export variable

Tags: shell, environment-variables

If I run

```
export COMMAND=nonexistentcommand && which $COMMAND >/dev/null || \
(echo "download filewithcommand.sh" && export COMMAND=./filewithcommand.sh)

echo "command: $COMMAND"
```

I get

```
download filewithcommand.sh
command: nonexistentcommand
```

But I think it should be

```
download filewithcommand.sh
command: ./filewithcommand.
```

What's wrong with this sentence?

Comment: For reference, see [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216) — specifically, section A.4 of the first answer.

Answer (score 3):

`COMMAND` is set to `nonexistentcommand` and that's the output that you get. Normal.

You do set `COMMAND` to some other value, but that's in a subshell (enclosed in parentheses) so it doesn't affect the environment of the parent shell. Did you mean to use `{` braces `}` (which don't fork a subshell) instead of `(` parentheses `)`?

Comment: Yeah. This is the good response. You are great ;). I just have had to add an ending semicolon at the end of the last command.